# How to take Kirlian photos?

Tags: kirlian-photography

What is the easiest way of taking Kirlian pictures (photographic techniques used to capture the phenomenon of electrical coronal discharges)?

> Kirlian photography, although the study of which can be traced back to
>   the late 1700s, was officially invented in 1939 by Semyon Davidovitch
>   Kirlian.  The Kirlian photographic process reveals visible “auras”
>   around the objects photographed.  These photographs have been the
>   subject of much myth and controversy over the years.

For clarification, I'm not concerned whether this is a digital or analog solution.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirlian_photography

Comment: You've tagged this "digital photography" - are you looking for a digital way of doing this? If so, that doesn't exist - Kirlian photography is a reaction between the coronal discharge and the chemicals in the film, and so can't be replicated in the digital domain.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not limit only to digital, but I couldn't find any other appropriate tags for it. Which tag are you suggesting instead, there need to be at least one.

Comment: I created a shiny new tag for you :-) It should even have a wiki summary when someone approves that.

Comment: Thanks:) I'm hoping this will encourge more questions about Kirlian photography.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Kirlian photography in the proper sense is a technique that makes [contact prints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_print) of objects directly on film without the use of lenses, it can not be done using a modern digital camera. The *auras* in Kirlian photos are caused by the reaction of the chemicals in the film to the electric current running through them. The same electric currents would not have a similar effect on a digital sensor viewing a scene through a lens from several feet away.

It is possible to use digital imaging devices to record the visible electrical discharge around flat objects if a transparent electrode plate is placed over the object and used for the positive charge.

Comment: One word: Photoshop :)

Answer (score 2):

Kirlian photograph is a high contact print photography. You can use a digital camera with a transparent discharge plate.

You can find equipment and additional information here:

http://www.imagesco.com/kirlian/index.html

and how to build your own equipment here:

http://www.imagesco.com/articles/kirlian/kirlian-photography.html

Comment: It sounds a bit like you are associated with this website. If so, you need to declare this association. Within the stackexchange community we like to have at least a summary of any link that is included in the answer.